# Disable invoices

Tags: invoice

We need to setup a store that will be using an external service for managing invoices (we always used magento's...). I have been searching for a while and couldn't find anything detailed enough.

As I understand, invoices are an integral part in the Magento order workflow. When payment is accepted, an invoice is automatically or manually generated (depending on payment method). An invoice is a permanent record of the order in the system. Thus, I don't feel it is a good idea to bypass invoices in the process.

We need to take into account:

- For an order to reach a complete status in magento, needs to be
  invoiced and totally shipped
- Invoices can trigger emails to customers (with their invoice)
- User account panel shows invoices for each order

I am wondering what is the best way to "disable invoices". Or at least in frontend, and keep processing orders as usual.(and magento invoices just won't be "legal").

Does it make sense to just disable invoice emails in the backend and disable any reference in xml / templates for `<customer_account>`?

Comment: @Jaimie Dijstra added an answer to my old question, but I don't see it anymore. Was it rejected? I think he was pretty accurate and good for this topic. Sorry if I misunderstood something...